# How to add a folder with a sh file to cmake to call the file via system()

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have a Source folder with a .sh file called `test.sh`. With c++ vi can call a .sh file with `system("Source/test.sh")`. How can i add the directory to the c++ project, so I can call the file if the executable is not in the root directory.

Comment: you mean you want to use absolute directory `system("/the/directory/to/the/test/script/test.sh"` ?

Comment: `execute_process()` or `add_custom_target()`.

Comment: I would copy the file to the c project, so the file is in the executable and not on the computer

Answer (score 0):

You can use execute_process as follow:

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c " your command"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE outVar
)
```

So if you want to copy your file:

```
set(MAKECMD "cp myf/ile")
list(APPEND MAKECMD ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c ${MAKE_CMD}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMDOUTPUT
)
```

for more info: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html